# When Kafka auto commit is enable, does same offset get committed multiple times?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let’s assume *enable.auto.commit=true*, and let’s assume that the topic I read message from has some long period of inactivities (no messages for let’s say 48h). As a result successive poll() call won’t return any message for 48h, my question is:

Will the last returned message’s offset (same one for 48h) be committed again and again each *auto.commit.interval.ms* in the *__consumer_offsets* topic, which is compacted and whose expiration is controlled by *offsets.retention.minutes* ?

Committing again and again would prevent the record in *__consumer_offsets* topic to expire and be deleted at some point.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting one.

**Edit**: Based on the recent comment, updating this. The updated portions are <s>strikedthrough</s> and marked either explicitly or in *italics*.

I would go with <s>"No"</s> *"Yes"* i.e. the last returned message's offset will <s>NOT</s> be committed again and again if no new messages have arrived in the topic.

Here's an explanation on the same.

A typical consumer example would look something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
<other-properties>
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
}
```

So, typically the responsibility of the offset commit sits with the consumer and is driven by the poll loop.

Now, in the scenario you've described after the last commit every call to the `poll()` method will return an empty map. <s>So, if there are no records returned by `poll()` then there are no new offsets to be committed.</s>

Here's how I traced through the source code of Kafka and arrived at this conclusion. The following return statement is from the `poll()` method definition given [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java)

```
return ConsumerRecords.empty();
```

Definition of the `empty()` method available in this [file](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecords.java).

**Edit**: The following portion is the new addition based on the comment from Gwen.

However, before the empty map is returned there is another `poll()` method (sitting in the `ConsumerCoordinator` class) is invoked via the `poll()` method of the `KafkaConsumer` class, which as per the definition given [here](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java). handles periodic offset commits if they are enabled via the following method:

```
public void maybeAutoCommitOffsetsAsync(long now) {
    if (autoCommitEnabled && now >= nextAutoCommitDeadline) {
        this.nextAutoCommitDeadline = now + autoCommitIntervalMs;
        doAutoCommitOffsetsAsync();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question. The answer is correct that poll() will return empty. BUT - what happens to the position (latest offset returned)? it won't change, because we need to use it again on the next fetch attempt. And the auto-commit will commit the same offsets again.

Look at ConsumerCoordinator.doAutoCommitOffsetsAsync() and see that it always commits current positions.

Comment: @GwenShapira - Thanks a lot for your comment/suggestion. :) After reading this, I retraced the source code and realised that I had completely missed the pollOnce() invocation in poll() method, which is invoking the poll() in ConsumerCoordinator that does the magic. Anyway, I've updated the answer from a "No" to a "Yes" and added some more explanation.